# Is there a good C implementation of Google Protocol Buffers

Tags: c, protocol-buffers

Google officially provides a C++ implementation of Google Protocol buffers,
but I'm looking for a C implementation.

I will not be using it myself, but my hope is that I can use this tool to generate
C code for our Google Protocol Buffer definitions which I can then hand of to the C developers.

I'm not looking for any RPC functionality, simply encoding and decoding of Google Protocol Buffer messages.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Use [protobuf-c](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/) (now at Github as [protobuf-c](https://github.com/protobuf-c/protobuf-c)).

From their official site:

> This package provides a code generator and runtime libraries to use
>   Protocol Buffers from pure C (not C++).
>
> It uses a modified version of `protoc` called `protoc-c`.

Comment: But from what I've read they are focussing on something other than the encoding and decoding of messages

Comment: Nevertheless, the message I/O is the foundation of protobufs. So they had to implement that, and you can ignore other functionality and even remove it from the runtime.

Answer (score 16):

There's also [Nanopb](http://koti.kapsi.fi/~jpa/nanopb/) which is more light-weight.

For example, it does not store message and field names in the code, so introspection (searching a field by name) is not possible.

Answer (score 5):

[pbtools](https://github.com/eerimoq/pbtools) is another alternative. It generates fast C source code to encode and decode protobuf messages.

Also, there is a list of more C implementations here: https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/docs/third_party.md

Answer (score 1):

[μpb](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/upb) is a small protobuf implementation written in C.

upb generates a C API for creating, parsing, and serializing messages as declared in .proto files. upb is heavily arena-based